# How to use xmonad in portrait mode/orientation?

Tags: x11

How does one use xmonad with the physical screens in portrait orientation?

I have two physical displays and they are both rotated 90 degrees to the right (clockwise with original bottom edges on the left)

I'm on Fedora 21 (3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64)

I don't know how to tell what window manager is running, but there's a `gnome-shell` process running...

When I `sudo telinit 3` and then `startx`, xmonad comes up with everything in landscape orientation. I don't know how to change it at that point and I don't know how to make it start in portrait mode.

My .xinitrc file says this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
emacs &
gnome-terminal &
exec xmonad
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all, your window manager seems to be `xmonad` ;-).
Independent of that, `xrandr` does what you need.

[Shamelessly taken from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/cannot-rotate-screen-with-xrandr) (because SO doesn't accept duplicates from unix.stackexchange.com):

Find your output devices with `xrandr` (the first word before "connected", you should find two such lines), e.g. eDP1 if the output is

```
eDP1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
```

and then have fun with

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate right
```

in your `.xinitrc`.

The original answer notices that by using a NVidia card you may have to add

```
Option    "RandRRotation" "True"
```

to your `xorg.conf` (which i cannot verify with my setup).

Comment: If you feel uncomfortable with command line, xrandr can  be configured via arandr, a simple visual frontend  that can generate shell scripts for your different configurations.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that I had to rotate left, which was unexpected given I'd have to rotate my head right in order to read the monitor logos on the bottom bezels of the screens which are now at the left edge.