# How do I 'arrange' my displays in xmonad?

Tags: x11

I have two physical displays. Currently xmonad thinks they are separated by some physical distance so when I move my cursor from one display to the next, the mouse disappears off the edge of one display and I have to keep moving the mouse some distance before it appears on the next display.

Another sign that they're misconfigured is when the screensaver shows an animation across both screens, there's a huge section from the middle that's missing (not that I actually care what the screensaver looks like)

In gnome, there's the display settings panel where you can drag one display's position relative to the other to match your physical reality (like if one monitor is slightly higher than the other)

What is the equivalent in xmonad?

If it helps, here is the output of xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected 1200x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200     59.95*+
1920x1080     59.99  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95  
1280x1024     60.02  
1280x960      60.00  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32  
640x480       60.00  
720x400       70.08  
DVI-0 connected primary 1200x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
1920x1200     59.95*+
1920x1080     59.99  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     60.02  
1280x960      60.00  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32  
640x480       60.00  
720x400       70.08
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your previous question, [Eric recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402955/how-to-use-xmonad-in-portrait-mode-orientation#comment46998441_29409953) to use `arandr` (a graphical frontend for `xrandr`) which lets you position the screens easily - i guess this can be done using `xrandr` as well, but here the GUI simplifies your life.

Again, this question is independent of xmonad. Since you were unsure which window manager you are using (in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402955/how-to-use-xmonad-in-portrait-mode-orientation)) i think you need to understand: xmonad is a window manager, as opposed to a desktop environment like KDE or Gnome. Using a window manager you'll have to rely on tools provided by GNU/Linux to do certain things, where a desktop environment often provides such tools, e.g. Screensaver, Screen locking, status bars and so on.